# Не работает парсер, когда посылаю гет запрос

Tags: python, scrapy

Решил сделать парсер, вот код парсера. Проблема в том что когда отправляю get запрос, то приходит странный html код, хотя статус код 200. Ещё и ни один тег не ищется почему то.

```
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    headers = {
        "accept": "*/*",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }
    
    
    def sign_in():
        work = Session()
        work.get("https://www.kijiji.ca", headers=headers)
        log = work.get("https://www.kijiji.ca/t-login.html", headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(log.text, "html.parser")
        print(soup)
    
    
    sign_in()
```

Вот пример html кода который приходит[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что на этой странице и есть именно такой html-код, парсер тут ни при чём, в браузере он такой же

Comment: "Ещё и ни один тег не ищется почему то" Все зависеть от того, что вы ищете и как.

Comment: я ищу тег input чтобы войти в аккаунт, но не тега input не других тегов парсер не находит, хотя через инспектор кода я его вижу на странице

Answer (score 0):

Парсер у вас РАБОТАЕТ и делает то, что должен.
У html-страницы, которую вы пытаетесь спарсить именно такая структура, это JS код, а не HTML, вероятно сайт использует какой либо фреймворк на подобии Vue или React.

Comment: А как тогда мне тогда получить html?

Comment: Попробуйте PHP browserext. У них даже есть документация на русском: https://github.com/scraperlab/browserext/blob/master/README-RU.md